# Не выводится изображение

Tags: php

Взял код с официального сайта и он не работает (убрал немного лишнего);

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

// Устанавливаем тип содержимого в заголовок, в данном случае image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

imagejpeg($im, '555.jpg');

// Освобождаем память
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Добавьте в конце `readfile('555.jpg')`. Ну и уберите `?>` закрывающий.

Comment: выводится только чёрный фон

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли залить картинку, ну и нарисовать на ней что нибудь.

Вы только сказали что хотите использовать цвет!

```
<?php
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 23, 14, 91);

    // Устанавливаем тип содержимого в заголовок, в данном случае image/jpeg
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bg_color);
    imagechar($im, 1, 0, 0, "H", $text_color );

    imagejpeg($im);

    // Освобождаем память
    imagedestroy($im);
```

Я так же убрал запись в файл.
Если нет необходимости можно сразу отдавать пользователю и не тратить IO диска.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagefttext.php - хороший пример из документации.